Application must hold android.permission.REQUEST_COMPANION_PROFILE_AUTOMOTIVE_PROJECTION connecting to DHU
I have Android 14 set up on a raspberry pi 4b using the konstakang build. It has basic LiteGapps and currently no third party apps. I have the developer modes enabled, head unit server running, and logs coming through.
I'm unable to get Android Auto to start up on DHU despite only having base apps installed. Has anyone come across a similar issue?
When I try to connect to android auto via USB using DHU 2.0, logs stop and I get stuck on Attached! in terminal and waiting for phone... in the DHU. When reconnecting logs I can see the following error:

2024-09-07 11:51:52.609  2791-3413  GH.CrashHandler         pid-2791
E  GH FATAL EXCEPTION: CarService
Process: com.google.android.projection.gearhead:car
PID: 2791
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to register vehicle with CDM
at hhs.m(SourceFile:131)
at hhs.c(SourceFile:75)
at obg.run(SourceFile:24)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:959)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:85)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
java.lang.SecurityException: Application must hold
android.permission.REQUEST_COMPANION_PROFILE_AUTOMOTIVE_PROJECTION to
associate with a device with
android.app.role.SYSTEM_AUTOMOTIVE_PROJECTION profile.
at cyt.k(SourceFile:21)
at cyt.get(SourceFile:20)
at cyy.get(SourceFile:2)
at hhs.m(SourceFile:39)
at hhs.c(SourceFile:75) 
at obg.run(SourceFile:24) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:959) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317) 
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:85) 
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Application must hold
android.permission.REQUEST_COMPANION_PROFILE_AUTOMOTIVE_PROJECTION to
associate with a device with
android.app.role.SYSTEM_AUTOMOTIVE_PROJECTION profile.
at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3183)
at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3167)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3150)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3092)
at
android.companion.ICompanionDeviceManager$Stub$Proxy.associate(ICompanionDeviceManager.java:878)
at
android.companion.CompanionDeviceManager.associate(CompanionDeviceManager.java:441)
at ew$$ExternalSyntheticApiModelOutline1.m(D8$$SyntheticClass:60)
at hfh.a(SourceFile:77)
at hhk.a(SourceFile:106)
at yf.d(SourceFile:19)
at hhs.m(SourceFile:27)
at hhs.c(SourceFile:75) 
at obg.run(SourceFile:24) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:959) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317) 
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:85) 
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
at
com.android.server.companion.utils.PermissionsUtils.enforcePermissionForRequestingProfile(PermissionsUtils.java:105)
at
com.android.server.companion.utils.PermissionsUtils.enforcePermissionForCreatingAssociation(PermissionsUtils.java:83)
at
com.android.server.companion.AssociationRequestsProcessor.processNewAssociationRequest(AssociationRequestsProcessor.java:171)
at
com.android.server.companion.CompanionDeviceManagerService$CompanionDeviceManagerImpl.associate(CompanionDeviceManagerService.java:713)
at
android.companion.ICompanionDeviceManager$Stub.onTransact(ICompanionDeviceManager.java:392)


For anyone finding this issue, I resolved it by using mindthegapps https://mindthegapps.com instead of Basic LiteGapps.
